# How to create annotations like @IBOutlet or @NSManaged in swift or objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, annotations

I am building a library so i would like to create some annotations like @IBOutlet or @NSManaged or @IBAction. I couldn't find any solution. Is there any way to create this kind of annotations in iOS?

Comment: Are you looking for [property wrappers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617)?

Comment: @Sweeper Got it. Thank you